# Resizing Disk on Azure Virtual Machine with Storage Pool

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I own a virtual machine (classic) on Azure that uses 4 data disks, each making 50 GB. These disks are grouped together in a storage pool.

Is it possible to increase the size (up to 100 GB for example) of disks despite the storage pool ?

I have already made a large increase on a single disk successfully (with powershell) but never on a storage pool.

I want to be sure that there is no danger to the data currently on the disks.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my knowledge, it is **not** possible to increase physical disk to expand storage pool.

As a workaround, maybe you can **resize your Azure VM** to a high size, then extend the pool by adding more physical disks.

You can use PowerShell to add physical disk `Add-PhysicalDisk`.

```
$toadd = Get-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName "Msft Virtual Disk"
Add-PhysicalDisk -StoragePoolFriendlyName poolname -PhysicalDisks $toadd
```

Comment: I can, indeed, add new physical disks to increase the size of the pool. The size of my virtual machine allows me to do that. But I would have preferred to increase the size of the discs directly. According to Micah_MSFT, it's possible.

Comment: Moving this to a comment - I do not believe it will make difference if the disks are in a storage pool. From an Platform standpoint the disks are all separate. It is only internally from the VMs perspective that the disks are one. Regardless, I always suggest making a copy of the VHD prior to making any changes just in case and would suggest a test before performing on any production servers.

Comment: @StevenPF You can increase the size of the physical disk, but you can't update the size of physical disk in storage pool. Please let me know if you need more help.

Comment: @StevenPF Does this work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)

Comment: I will test that this weekend and I inform you.

Comment: @StevenPF ok, feel free let me know if you need more help:)